# Script file restart Tomcat runs manually success, but fails on Crontab

Tags: cron, tomcat7, restart

I'm newbie to shell scripting.
I have a Tomcat server build on : `/APP/apache-tomcat-7.0.42`

I want my tomcat automatic restart one time per day, so I write a file `test.sh` (`/APP/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/test.sh`) with content :

```
/APP/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/bin/shutdown.sh && echo "Tomcat was already shutdown"
kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:8080 -sTCP:LISTEN)
/APP/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/bin/startup.sh
```

And I install on crontab: **0 9 * * * /APP/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/test.sh**

But not working, although I try run manually, and success.

I checked crontab : `/etc/init.d/crond` status, it is running.

I dont understand, help me!

Comment: Oh, I resloved!
If you can do it manually, from a log in session, but not automatically from
startup or from cron, I'm 99% sure it's because environment variables like
JAVA_HOME and CATALINA_HOME are not being set for the startup and cron environments.
So, add lines to that Crontab:
export PATH="/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/tomcat/bin"
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_41"
export CATALINA_HOME="/APP/apache-tomcat-7.0.42"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I resloved!

If you can do it manually, from a log in session, but not automatically from
startup or from cron, I'm 99% sure it's because environment variables like
JAVA_HOME and CATALINA_HOME are not being set for the startup and cron environments.

You need get info in this session:

**> echo $JAVA_HOME**

**> JAVA_HOME="/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_41"**

**> echo $CATALINA_HOME**

**> CATALINA_HOME="/APP/apache-tomcat-7.0.42"**

Then, Result file crontab:

**export PATH="/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/tomcat/bin"**

**export JAVA_HOME="/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_41"**

**export CATALINA_HOME="/APP/apache-tomcat-7.0.42"**

**/APP/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/bin/shutdown.sh**

**kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:8080 -sTCP:LISTEN)**

**/APP/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/bin/startup.sh**